# Getting fatal error whit localhost

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    global $user_ID, $user_identity; get_currentuserinfo(); if (!$user_ID) { 
    ?>
```

Every time I Try to open my document on Local host I get fatal error on that line

If anyone can help me fix the problem I would be very happy

Comment: could u share the entire code !!

Comment: What does the error say

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 158

Comment: You haven't defined `get_currentuserinfo()` anywhere, so there you go.

Comment: The entire code is to long to be in here

Comment: You haven't defined get_currentuserinfo() anywhere, so there you go. – h2ooooooo 1 min ago 

I know but i already defind it so thats why i need help

Comment: is get_currentuserinfo() a function within a class?

Comment: could anyone write a code that defines it so I can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling function `get_currentuserinfo()` without defining it first. From your comments I take it you confuse definition with declaration in PHP. Defining a function doesn't mean declaring its name like you would with a variable. You have to actually implement it.

```php
function get_currentuserinfo(){
    // your code here
}
```